# FTP upload - memory leak problem

Tags: c#, memory-leaks, upload, ftp

I'm working on a personal project that uploads and downloads big files using FTP protocol. It's working fine except the memory leak that I recently noticed. I don't know exactly what the problem is. It could be memory leak or bad programming. The memory amount used by this application increasing every second while uploading. Here is the code:

```
    Action action;
    int bufferSize = 16384;
    EventLogger elog = new EventLogger();
    string error = "";
    string filename = "";

    public Uploader(Action action)
    {
        this.action = action;
        filename = action.directory.Substring(action.directory.LastIndexOf('\\') + 1,
            action.directory.Length - action.directory.LastIndexOf('\\') - 1);
    }

    public bool startUpload()
    {   
        try
        {
            FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://*******");
            request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory;
            request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("***", "***");

            FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

            Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream);
            List<string> files = new List<string>();
            string[] filesArr = reader.ReadToEnd().Split('\n');
            reader.Close();
            response.Close();
            foreach (string file in filesArr)
                files.Add(file.Replace("\r", ""));
            if (files.IndexOf(filename) != -1)
            {
                request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://***/"+filename);
                request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DeleteFile;
                request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("***", "***");
                response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
                reader.Close();
                response.Close();
                if (response.StatusCode != FtpStatusCode.FileActionOK)
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }

            request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://***/"+filename);
            request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
            request.KeepAlive = false;
            request.UseBinary = true;

            FileStream stream = File.OpenRead(action.directory);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
            Stream reqStream = request.GetRequestStream();

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = "update DIRECT_UPLOAD set COMPLETED = @com, PROGRESS = @prog, SPEED = @speed where ID = @id";
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", action.id);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@com", 0);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prog", 0);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@speed", 0);


            long i = 0;
            int readed = 0;
            int total = 0;
            int speed = 0;
            DateTime last = DateTime.Now;
            int lastTotal = 0;
            while ((readed = stream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferSize)) > 0)
            {
                reqStream.Write(buffer, 0, readed);
                total += readed;
                if (i % 100 == 0)
                {
                    cmd.Parameters["@com"].Value = total;
                    cmd.Parameters["@prog"].Value = (int)(((double)total / action.size) * 100);
                    int tot = 0;
                    tot = total - lastTotal;
                    int time = Convert.ToInt32((DateTime.Now - last).TotalMilliseconds);
                    speed = (int)(((double)1000.0 / time) * tot);
                    cmd.Parameters["@speed"].Value = speed;
                    if ((error = SqlProcess.sqlNonQuery(cmd)) != "")
                        throw new Exception(error);
                    last = DateTime.Now;
                    lastTotal = total;
                }

                Application.DoEvents();
                i++;
            }

            cmd.Parameters["@com"].Value = total;
            cmd.Parameters["@prog"].Value = 100;
            cmd.Parameters["@speed"].Value = 0;
            if ((error = SqlProcess.sqlNonQuery(cmd)) != "")
                throw new Exception(error);

            reqStream.Close();
            stream.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            elog.write(ex);
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Thank you.

Comment: First of all, you should use the using-statement for all instances of classes that implements IDisposable (like Stream) to be sure they get closed and cleaned up even when an exception occurs

Answer (score 1):

Check all the objects you use here to make sure they do not need to be `Dispose`-d (i.e. do they implement `IDisposable`?). Otherwise, you will experience a leak of unmanaged resources associated with each of those objects every time this code executes.

You can use `using` to tidily ensure that `Dispose()` is called for such objects, in an exception-safe way.

Example - instead of:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
```

use this to wrap the code that uses `cmd`

```
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
{
}
```

Note that your `EventLogger` class may also need to implement `IDisposable` if it's a custom class that wraps unmanaged resources through (for example) `File` or `EventLog`.

You can check the other built-in classes that you use here and elsewhere in your program in the MSDN docs.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will implement your suggestions. But is that kind of bad programming cause 200 MB extra memory use in 5 minutes? Application uses 25 MB memory at start.

Comment: Extra memory use is not always due to leaks - use of the managed heap and Garbage Collection by the CLR means that you cannot correlate process size with actual application memory use directly.  I would try this and see what happens. If you want detailed memory usage info on your process, you will have to use a CLR profiler that allows 'live' object instances to be tracked.